# Docker image alpine java 8?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I have been looking for Java 8 alpine or non-alpine docker image. I cannot find them as so many docker images are available that have no explanation regarding the version.

This is where I am searching:
https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/tags

Following is the java version which I want:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found some of the following official Docker images:

```
openjdk                                                               8-jdk-alpine         a3562aa0b991   3 years ago         105MB
openjdk                                                               8-jdk-alpine3.9      a3562aa0b991   3 years ago         105MB
openjdk                                                               8-jdk-alpine3.8      21a93502ddd8   3 years ago         103MB
openjdk                                                               8-jdk-alpine3.7      1caad94162ef   4 years ago         102MB
```

Comment: The [openjdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk) images are no longer supported.

Comment: Cool, then what image to use for Java?